# Oracle: create a new table whenever I update the status of an employee

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following table and I want to create a new table whenever I update the status of an employee to "confirm." The new table must contain all columns with data of that particular employee.

```
 SQL> select * from employee;

 EMPID EMPNAME                          SAL DOJ       STATUS
 ----- ------------------------- ---------- --------- --------------------
   101 ALEX                           10000 12-MAY-16 not_confirmed
   102 PETER                          20000 12-MAY-16 not_confirmed
```

Comment: That's a very odd solution... (I.e. most probably the wrong solution. Tell us the problem instead, and perhaps we can give you a much better alternative.)

Comment: Do you really want to create a new table every time you update an employee? It would make more sense to create a new row in an employee_history table when you update an employee.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Well its a demo. we r trying to implement these programs(queries) in our our project.Can we do it by calling the procedure inside trigger? @OTTA

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's a demo or not. Still a bad idea.

Comment: A trigger would be one way, or you could wrap the update and the insert up in a transaction, all very much depends on what you're trying to do and why, which isn't clear from your post.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new table for employee with the same structure of table employee, e.g. employee_history.

Create a trigger After Update to insert old values in the history table
The code can be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF( UPDATING( 'STATUS' ) )
 THEN
   INSERT INTO employee_history( EMPID, EMPNAME, SAL , DOJ,STATUS)
     VALUES( :old.EMPID, :old.EMPNAME , :old.SAL , :old.DOJ ,  :old.STATUS);
 END IF;
```

END;

You can add extra tracking fields (if needed ) like update_date , user_id (who do changes , ..)

Comment: this should be the correct answer, but logically shouldn´t the history contain the `:old` values?

Comment: @Kevin: thanks. History tables usually involve making a complete copy of the original  row when something changes in the source table. Reference: http://database-programmer.blogspot.com.eg/2008/07/history-tables.html

Comment: Thanks again. Good Point,  I will modify the code to use :old

Comment: 1. An additional `date` column would be handy. 2. Use `:new` to record what values were changed to at that date/time. 3. Make the trigger after _insert_ and update to capture the initial value.

Comment: @Shannon: I agree with you, sometimes may be needed adding  all changes to  columns with  old and new values including column name, which may lead to use a generic history table with common structure for all critical tables.